# How to generate promo code for android app subscription?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscription

I want to generate promo code for my app subscription, but when i 
         go to promotion on google play console and trying to add/GET, it 
         just give a message

> This product is not available for promotion.

Please help me if any one have any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Promo codes are for InApp products only. We cannot use promo codes for `subscriptions`.

Refer https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/01/create-promo-codes-for-your-apps-and-in.html **Tips section**

Comment: Thank you subham but it is not exactly I want this is for in-app purchase but I want for subscription

Answer (score 0):

To use promo codes for in-app products, you should implement In-app Promotions in your app. **Note that promo codes can’t be used for subscriptions.**

android-developers.google

Answer (score 0):

In the "create promotions" Google support page:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6321495

it specifically states:

"For subscription promotions, you can create up to 10,000 promo codes per quarter per subscription product. This does not count towards the limit of promo codes for managed products."

Answer (score 0):

As per new google policy, Promo Codes can be used for Subscriptions. Check
[Google Play Promo Codes](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/promo)